# Enter military time in Excel without ":"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using this script I found on the Microsoft forum to allow me to enter military time without having to enter the ":" every time. It works fine, until I add a blank row or delete a row. Then I get an error. How can I get this code to ignore deletions and additions in the range that don't meet the expected format?

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
 Dim xHour As String
 Dim xMinute As String
 Dim xWord As String
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 xWord = Format(Target.Value, "0000")
 xHour = Left(xWord, 2)
 xMinute = Right(xWord, 2)
 On Error Resume Next
 Target.Value = TimeValue(xHour & ":" & xMinute)
 On Error Resume Next
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: Add `If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub` for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Target` is a multi-cell range, then `Format(Target.Value, "0000")` will throw a Type Mismatch error, since `Target.Value` is a 2-D Variant array.

So bail early if `Target` is more than one cell, with

```
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
```

Also, the extra `On Error Resume Next` is extraneous...